# Magento 2 / Intercept Array REST API Call with a Plugin?

Tags: magento2, plugin, array, extrafee

is it possible to intercept the sales order API array export to manipulate the array?

I've installed the Amasty Extrafee Extention, but our Merchandise Management System cannot work with this export.

I have to intercept this informations and at it as a "Product" to the items.

Comment: Any updates on this question? I'm looking for the same

Comment: Yes, i have made a custom Modul for that

Comment: Will you be able to share as an Answer if possible?